# NT Hosted WCF Service With MSMQ fails to stop cleanly and Locks Up

Tags: wcf, service, msmq

This is a problem which has had me baffled for weeks now on a client's Live environment.

The WCF service is hosted on Windows Server 2003, and has both HTTP and MSMQ endpoints.

When placing the service in the test environment, the service cleanly starts and stops, and messages are passed without problems. However on the Live environment, the service starts fine, but does not exit cleanly.

When attempting to stop the service, the machine takes a long time to respond and eventually displays an error saying that the service could not be stopped. Inspecting the error on the event log, it says that it was unable to write to the MSMQ queue (access denied), however, the service is able read and remove messages from the queue. If one then refreshes the service manager, the service is in fact stopped.

The MSMQ queue is hosted on a different physical machine, and we have been unable to reproduce the error on the test environment.

We are not sure if it is related or not, but the service will also occasionally stop pulling messages from the queue. This has been solved by restarting the service. Again, we have not been able to reproduce the error.

Recently we experienced another error with the HTTP based client where upon midnight one night, the service suddenly started rejecting connections with the following exception:

`The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

Even more curious, is that simply restarting the service seems to correct the problem.

If anyone has seen anything like this before or has any comments, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Service is hosted using the ServiceModelEx library

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to a colleague, apparently setting the ServiceModelEx throttling options all to "1" help with the lock ups on MSMQ based WCF services.